# Install Fedora 20 via USB CD check failed

Tags: fedora, live-usb

I am trying to run Fedora 20 (`Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1.iso`) from an USB stick on my laptop.
Unfortunately I keep running into these warnings:

```
Warning: dracut: Fatal: CD check failed!
Warning: dracut: Refusing to continue
Warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist
```

Then it enters some kind of emergency mode and allows me to use the dracut command line.

I have tried both UNetbootin and dd to create the bootable USB from my current Ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo dd if=Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=8M && sync
```

I used both 4M and 8M for the `bs` value. For 8M this results in:

```
10+1 records in
10+1 records out
87397591 bytes (87 MB) copied, 18.5976 s, 4.7 MB/s
```

Which seems far too low to me.

Comment: Check if `sha256sum Fedora-Live-Desktop-x86_64-20-1.iso` produce this checksum: `cc0333be93c7ff2fb3148cb29360d2453f78913cc8aa6c6289ae6823372a77d2`

Comment: Something is indeed wrong because I have a different checksum: `be6a95f4db77f52b45cb35686106876b16693b5638d59f172e4d75579b52f53a`. But I got it from the `fedoraproject.org` site. Suggestions @ArturSzymczak ?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/pl/static/checksums/Fedora-Live-x86_64-20-CHECKSUM

Comment: I have downloaded it again, this time the checksum checks out. I will try again. This time at least 999 MB are copied.

Comment: @ArturSzymczak that was the problem. Currently writing this from my Fedora Live :)

Comment: Nice to read that :)